# How to select MAX date of each month in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to extract max date of each month for a later join to extract in results the records/rows that match (inner join) this max date in Transact-SQL for SQL Server

Main problem is that in the step before I convert dates that exactly match Sunday 1st or Sunday 2nd of the month substracting 1 or 2 days respecitvely. After that I tried a select I used for Max Date of every week of the year (similar behaviour) but it didnt work

I have this Select for max date of each week and no problem

```
SELECT max([date_field]) as date,
FROM [database].[dbo].[Table]
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CAST([date] AS NVARCHAR(25)), 8,4) ,Week_Number
ORDER BY week_Number ASC;
```

But aplying same behaviour with the month can't Select the registers converted from 1st and 2nd of mont

```
SELECT max([date_field]) as date,
FROM [database].[dbo].[Table]
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CAST([date] AS NVARCHAR(25)), 8,4) ,month_Number
ORDER BY month_Number ASC;
```

in this case It should return Max Date in June case -> 31-5-2019 (date that doenst appear in database and we converted it from 2nd june), but retuned 30-5-2019, this one appears but 31-5-2019 is bigger so it shouldnt be returned

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add some sample data with your expected output?

Comment: `It should return Max Date in June case -> 31-5-2019` Why `31-5-2019` is in June ?

Comment: Yeah for sure,
Imagine that before converting it is 2019-06-02 00:00:00.000 after converting it all records are 2019-05-31 00:00:00.000 so It will be the Max record for the month and the data expected. With the SELECT Query used above it only retrieve 2019-05-30 00:00:00.000 (the old max record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT max([date_field]) as date,
FROM [database].[dbo].[Table]
GROUP BY month([date])
ORDER BY month(date) ASC;
```

Comment: It definitely helped me, i ordered based on Week_Num, that after the transformation wasnt changed so i just take the month of record and it worked! Thanks

Comment: This won't work for more than one year, so if you want the last date of sales in a month over multiple years this won't work. I will try adjusting the group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT working_area, MAX(commission) 
FROM agents 
GROUP BY working_area;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you might have more than one year in the database, you should include the year in the calculation:

```
SELECT MAX(t.date_field) as date,
FROM [database].[dbo].[Table] t
GROUP BY YEAR(t.date_field), MONTH(t.date_field)
ORDER BY MAX(t.date_field) ASC;
```

Similarly, your code for week is taking year into account, albeit quite inelegantly.